# How to overcome multiple @Produces methods?

Tags: java, cdi

I have javaEE application in which i have factory class which has multiple @Produces methods. This method produce classes that i use in application with @Inject annotation. The issue is, when i want to add new @Produce method i need to write it manually. How can I register all classes in loop (lets say with some custom annotation) so that i dont need to have so many @produces methods, but i can still use @inject?

Example of factory:

```
public class Factory {
    @Produces
    public DaoX daoX() {
        return this.jdbi.onDemand(DaoX.class);
    }

    @Produces
    public DaoY daoY() {
        return this.jdbi.onDemand(DaoY.class);
    }
}
```

Usage of daos:

```
    @Inject
    private DaoX daoX;

    @Inject
    private DaoY daoY;
```

Thx for help!

Comment: This is definitely doable with a CDI portable extension. It needs some experimentation but, although not trivial, it is not super complicated either.

Comment: [This](https://lairdnelson.wordpress.com/2017/02/11/dynamic-cdi-producer-methods/) seems to be a very good read, close to what you are looking for.